# Dynamically setting path to static file in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, dynamic, path

In Django, I'm trying to dynamically set the path to a static JavaScript file in a subfolder parsed from the URL. Not sure if this a good way to do it in Django (i.e. best practice), or if I am completely off.  It seems like way too many steps and not very DRY, especially the `views.py` code.  Will Django allow me to parse the request in the view (base.html) template and bypass the views.py step? I could use JavaScript, but is it possible in Django?

Static file configuration has been defined in `myproject/myproject/settings.py` as:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My static files are set up as follows

> Note: each main.js file contains scripts specific to that page.

```
/static/
└── js/
    ├── global.js
    ├── home/
    │   └── main.js  
    ├── projects/
    │   └── main.js  
    └── users/
        └── main.js
```

If this is my URL:

```
http://example.com/projects
```

Views.py: I set a file path relative to my STATIC_URL path

```py
def projects(request):
    context={'js_file':'js/projects/main.js'}
    return render(request, 'pages/projects.html',{'context':context})
```

Which I use in my base.html layout template to set the JavaScript path

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- template head content -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- template content -->
    <script src="{% static context.js_file %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This renders the following path

```html
<script src="/static/js/projects/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why in context?? that's wrong, you need to create static folder in your directory, then paste or create your js or css files there.

Comment: @SerioUs I don't want to set a hard path in every template, rather, set the dynamic path in the layout once, upload the appropriate JS file to the appropriate folder, and have the path render.   If you think this incorrect, please explain.

Comment: I have created a static folder.  I have added my static assets.  I have used the static path in many other places just fine.  That's not a problem and very straightforward.  

Where I'm confused is how best to DYNAMICALLY set the path to a static asset in my layout file.  My layout file is reused for many requests, but the specific static asset I want to use will vary depending on the request.  So I'd like to dynamically set the path to the static asset (i.e.  /static/js/`folder-changes-with-request`/main.js)